# Ligatures in 'shelfful'

Tags: writing, compounds

I came across the following text while going through [TeX documentation](ftp://ftp.ctex.org/pub/tex/documents/texguru/homepage/node28-2.html):

> ### `textcompwordmark`
>
> This command is used to separate letters which would normally
>   ligature. For example `fi` is produced with `f\textcompwordmark i`.
>   Note that the `f` and `i` have not ligatured to produce `fi`. This is
>   rarely useful in English (*`shelfful` is a rare example of where it
>   might be used*) but is used in languages such as German.

Since **ligature** was a new word for me, I immediately referenced my dictionary and found that:

> Noun: ligature
>
> Character consisting of two or more letters combined into one

[Wikipedia](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_ligature#Stylistic_ligatures) entry shows an example as:

[image: high-resolution image of fi and fl ligatures]

So, it means that the horizontal cross line in `f` is merged with the next character. But, I do not see something similar happening in the text when `shelfful` is being written. I'd assume that the horizontal lines of both `f`s in `ff` would get merged when writing, but this should be happening to each and every word which has `ff` appearing in them.

Why is such that all references (at least the ones I saw) only point out **shelfful** to be the rare example? Why not *scaffold* or *afford* or *effort* etc.?

PS: For the scope of this question, I'm restricting to ligatures with the leading character `f` only.

Comment: As a question about English typography conventions, this has nothing to do with learning English.

Comment: @200_success: The answer reveals it to be a semantic consideration, based on whether it is, or isn't, a conglomeration of two independent words. This seems as relevant as discussions of hyphenation.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Either way, I don't think this is a topic for ELL. I would bet that 99% of native English speakers would be unaware. It's also a non-issue in spoken English, hand-written English, and in typical computer text such as e-mail.

Comment: I'm neither particularly for nor against whether this question is on-topic or not (because I believe that we can take it both ways), but I'd like to add my idea from a learner's point of view. It's true that *ligature* is typographical term, and that may make this question off-topic. On the other hand, many of our users, I believe, learn English for their education, and it's quite likely that they will run into the word *ligature* when they have to typeset their essays, theses, or dissertations in their academic writing, and knowing what *ligature* means can be useful or even crucial, imho.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Shelfful* is different from *scaffold* because it is a compound word (*shelf + full*), so the two f's are truly separate. Removing the ligature between the f's re-emphasizes this construction. *Selffulfilling* is another one that makes a little more sense without the ligature (`selffulfilling`).

Not all fonts ligature anyways, so in my browser *shelffull* and "shelffull" have a ligature, but monospaced fonts (`shelffull` *`shelffull`*) do not.

(see image below)

[image]

EDIT: Ahhh....apparently some designers do offer monospaced fonts with ligatures  - Nathan Tuggy gives [Monoid](http://larsenwork.com/monoid/) as an example.

Comment: Note that some monospaced fonts (e.g. [Monoid](http://larsenwork.com/monoid/)) *do* have ligatures. It's just a matter of designer taste.

Comment: There are even monospaced fonts with ligatures designed for software development, like [Fira Code](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Fira+Code), which renders ligatures for things like `>=`, `!=`, and `->` to look like ≥, ≠, and →.